# Cannot retrieve the data sent with the jQuery Ajax call .load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select, load

I am trying to retrieve on server-side the value from the `selected option` sent using a `jQuery .load()` call like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $("#first").change(function () {
            $("#second").load('populate_section.php?year=', {first: $(this).val()});
          });
        });
</script>

<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="first" name="year">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="second" name="section">
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then how I try to retrieve the value in my `PHP` code :

```
<?php
$year = $_GET['year']; // for test only
echo "<option>" . $year . "</option>";
?>
```

I assume here that the result will be a dropdown box with a value of whatever I chose on the first dropdown. However, it seems that var `$year` is empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set any value for **"year"** GET variable in the URL.
If you need to send **$(this).val()** as the **"year"**, do it like below code.

```
$("#second").load('populate_section.php', {"year": $(this).val()});
```

Comment: Using a `mapping` gives a `POST` method, not a `GET` (with jQuery 1.5.1). One must provide a string to send the request as GET. The string must be of the format `param1=v1&param2=v2&...` which can be obtained with the `$("my_form-or-my-fields-selector").serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(function () {
      $("#first").change(function () {
        $("#second").load('populate_section.php', {year: $(this).val()});
      });
    });
```